# React and ApolloClient returning different response with the same variables

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have a React project with a parent component and two child components.
In the child component there's a filter that returns a value to the parent.

`const { value, setValue} = useValueParams();`

This value is passed in a ApolloQuery like so:

`const response = useApolloQuery({ variables: { ...value }, fetchPolicy: 'no-cache', })`

The useApolloQuery is a graphQl call to our backend.

Because of re-renders this gets called 5 times when selecting a value.

I would expect the same response for all calls, but the last response, number 5, returns different data than the other 4, with the same variables...

And, one more thing: The strangest thing is, when I look in the network tab when I inspect the page, the response there is still correct...

What is React doing between the response from the back-end (which is correct) and the response in my React page??

Thanks!

I logged all responses, when I see the last response, the data is indeed incorrect while the "previousData" object in my call is still correct!